# Installing driver for Atheros AR8131

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, install-from-source

I am having the same trouble as others getting my Atheros AR8131 Ethernet card recognised by Ubuntu 12.10 on my new HP Pavillion P7-1449 PC. I found the same question where the answer suggested the following:

1. Download Tarball `compact-wireless-3.6.8-1-snpc`
2. Run

   ```
   ./scripts/driver-select alx
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

The problem is when I run the `make` command I get the following:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-21-generic/build M=/home/chris/Downloads/compat-wireless-3.6.8-1-snpc modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.5.0-21-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Found a link to an alternative patch file (compat-wireless-2012-09-25-pc) but then I get the similar error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-21-generic/build M=/home/chris/Desktop/compat-wireless-2012-09-25-pc modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.5.0-21-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried installing the compat-wireless packages provided by Ubuntu in the repositories? The latest 3.6 is available as a package: [`linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic). Compiling from source should be attempted only as a last resort, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't know that existed (I'm new to Linux). Up until now I've been googling and/or checking out this website for solutions to my problems. Check it out and it looks to me like the best candidates are  linux-source-3.5.0 or module-init-tools - or do you suggest applying all. Thanks again.

Comment: "Check it out and it looks to me like the best candidates are linux-source-3.5.0 or module-init-tools - or do you suggest applying all." Please rephrase that, I don't get your question in there. And what's the point of downloading the whole Linux kernel source code?

Comment: Unfortunately use of this operating system and website assume in-depth knowledge. In fact, I don't know what any of those links mean. I don't know how to download or deploy any of those files and for the record, I assumed they were patches rather than " the whole Linux kernel source code". On closer look I see the heading "Backported wireless drivers for generic kernel image" but there is nothing listed under that heading so I assume that the driver I need is not made it to the list.

Comment: Compiling from source in the first day of Ubuntu isn't the right thing to do. Let me rephrase my first comment in practical terms. 1) Open terminal. 2) run `sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic` 3) reboot 4) report back.

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm now - and I was also able to format my external hard drive as well (which I couldn't do previously). Now onto setting up Myth and Plex.  Thanks again.

Comment: Good to hear that. I've provided it as an answer now. Consider accepting and/or upvoting it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install drivers for the Atheros AR8161 Ethernet controller?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/165192/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-atheros-ar8161-ethernet-controller)

Answer (score 1):

The instructions to install compat-wireless modules are good, but in recent Ubuntu releases, this has been packaged and **there's no need to compile this from source anymore!** So, let's take a step back and look at another much simpler approach to install it.

Simply install the appropriate `linux-backports-modules-cw-*` package for your kernel, e.g.:

- For Quantal, using Linux compat-wireless-3.6 backported to regular kernel

  ```
  sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic
  ```
- Same, but for Precise

  ```
  sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-precise-generic
  ```

Or use any other package management tool to install this package. While it has 'backport' in its package name, it's not needed to enable any backports repository - it's just there in `main`.

Finally, reboot, or if you know the kernel module to load: `sudo modproble modulename`.

Answer (score 1):

Lately the modules from the 3.8 kernel have been backported, so use

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.8-precise-generic
```

instead of

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-precise-generic
```

as in [gertvdijk's answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/234553/223150)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, there is no need of compilation. Alx module which only works with my AR8161 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is gone. So download, and compile works for me.

I have to download some older package from compact wireless website which ALX module contains as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165192/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-atheros-ar8161-ethernet-controller).

```
wget -O- http://linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-pc.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 0):

no, that will not help. 
The last version that contains alx module is version 3.4, unfortunately.

so a regular user with this network card is completely dumped :(

and each time I upgrade to a new version of kernel once a few months, I have to waste one hour trying to figure out where did the linux magicians hide my network card driver!
anybody's been curious why Linux fails on Desktop? this is why! :(

why cannot they just move it where all the other network card drivers are?

so the proper command is:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.4-precise-generic
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.4-precise-generic-pae
```

depending on which magic version of kernel you magically use...